# How can I setup View helpers in the views directory?

Tags: zend-framework

I want to setup a helpers directory under views and place my view helpers there.

I have setup a test view helper in application/My/App/View/Helper/

I declared the class like so: class My_App_View_Helper_test extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract

I setup the the Bootstrap.php file like so: $view->setHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/My/App/View/Helper','My_App_View_Helper');

This is working perfectly. I learned to do this from zendcasts.
But I cannot set it up the way I want to. How do I set up helpers in views/helpers/ ?
What are the rules regarding the directory naming conversion? Where do I use plural and where do I use capitalization when naming directories?

I thank you in advance for your help.

sincerely,
a complete noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a helper named `Application_View_Helper_MyHelper` in `application/views/helpers`.

In your bootstrap you should have the following:

```
$view->setHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/helpers','Application_View_Helper');
```

Here, you simply register new plugin prefix for view helpers - `Application_View_Helper` and point Zend Framework to look for classes with this prefix in the following path - `APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/helpers`

Answer (score 1):

You can place the helpers in /view/helpers but you'll need to change your class name. The prefix needs to be `Zend_View_Helper_`

So, a class like `Zend_View_Helper_MyHelper` should work for you.

I found a blog post on usage, if you're interested : http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-view-helpers/

From the post

> A typical Zend Framework project using
>   Zend_Application, such as that
>   generated using the zf command line
>   tool, will have a folder called
>   helpers within the views folder for
>   each module. There will also be a
>   helpers folder within the layouts
>   folder too. If you place your view
>   helper in one of these helpers
>   folders, then the prefix is
>   Zend_View_Helper_.